How add frame subtitle with equal height inside a tcolorbox
i am using tcolorbox to do two column and then itemize inside. All work fine, but when I add subtitles with the command tcbsubtitle the frames not equal, it is adjusted by the height of the words.
This my code:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[text width=\textwidth,sidebyside,sidebyside align=top,title=\centering{Objetivos},subtitle style={boxrule=0.4pt,
colback=gray!50},frame style={fill=white}]
    \tcbsubtitle{De enseñanza}
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
        \item \lipsum[1]
        \item \lipsum[2]
    \end{itemize}
    \tcblower\tcbsubtitle{De aprendizaje}
        \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
            \item \lipsum[3]
            \item \lipsum[4]
        \end{itemize}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}

and the result

How to correct the height?
Thanks in advanced

Specify text height? Or include \strut into the content.

Off-topic: please consider using a better contrast between the test of your subtitles and the background. White-on-pale-grey is really quite difficult to read for me - and my eyesight, though not great, is not terrible or anything. If your audience consists entirely of trainee fighter pilots, you can ignore this plea.

The issue is due to the presence of descenders in only one of the subtitles. The difference can be eliminated by making the subtitles have the same total height (height + depth). There are many possible solutions. For example, you can include a \strut into the contents of the subtitles when needed or adjust the text height globally. Since you seem to be applying styles only locally, the code below demonstrates how to adjust the text height locally, too.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[%
    text width=\textwidth,
    sidebyside,
    sidebyside align=top,
    title=\centering{Objetivos},
    subtitle style={%
      boxrule=0.4pt,
      colback=gray!50,
      text height=2ex,
    },
    frame style={%
      fill=white,
    },
  ]
  \tcbsubtitle{De enseñanza}
  \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item \lipsum[2]
  \end{itemize}
  \tcblower\tcbsubtitle{De aprendizaje}
  \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
    \item \lipsum[3]
    \item \lipsum[4]
  \end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}

Image omitted due to a bug in Okular-on-X.
